# Message: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Tags: php, array

Desde hace dos semanas he venido presentando este error en el aplicativo de la empresa donde trabajo y actualmente mi conocimiento de php es muy poco con respecto a como solventar este inconveniente

Actualmente hay un apartado el cual es para subida de archivos y presenta fallos en una linea de codigo (Linea 34 la cual utiliza el metodo **count**) y en esa linea hace un ciclo for el cual lee los datos recibidos mediante un csv desde la interfaz, he visto en muchos ejemplos de resulto los cuales mencionan que no lo está tomando como array pero sinceramente no se como cambiar esa linea para que sea en un formato que el `count` reconozca.

A continuación dejo el método completo y la linea que esta tomando el error en la cual está un ciclo `for`:

```php
public function importRecordsCampaignSave(){
        $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
        $data = json_decode($json,true);  /* ahora en $data tenemos el objeto que nos enviaron x json, */
        $idCam = $data[0]["idcam"];
        $questions = "";
        $questions = "id_reg,".$this->importcampaigns_model->getQuestions($idCam);
        $questionsArray = explode(",", $questions);
        $error = 0;
        $errorString = "";
        $success = 0;
        $sqlclause = "";
        $table = "campania".$idCam;
        **for ($i = 0; $i < count($data[0]["datos"]); $i++) {**
            $sql = array();
            $j=0;
            foreach ($data[0]["datos"][$i] as $key => $value) {
                if($j == 0) $valId = $value;
                $valupper = upper_acentos(strtoupper($value));
                $sql[] = (is_numeric($value)) ? "`$questionsArray[$j]` = $valupper" : "`$questionsArray[$j]` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($valupper) . "'";
                $j++;
            }
            $sqlclause = implode(",", $sql);
            $result = $this->importcampaigns_model->validImport($table,$valId);
            if ($result){
                $rs = $this->importcampaigns_model->updateImport($table,$sqlclause,$valId);
                if ($rs){
                    $success++; 
                }else{
                    $error++;
                    $errorString .= "[Reg N°: ".$i." id: ".$valId."]";
                }
            }else{
                $rs = $this->importcampaigns_model->addImport($table,$sqlclause);
                if ($rs){
                    $success++; 
                }else{
                    $error++;
                    $errorString .= "[Reg N°: ".$i." id: ".$valId."]";
                }
            }
        }
        if($success == 0){
            echo json_encode(array("respuesta" => "failed"));
        }else{
            if($error == 0){
                echo json_encode(array("respuesta" => "success"));
            }else{
                echo json_encode(array("respuesta" => "success_failed","msg" => $errorString));
            }
            
        }
}
```

Muchas gracias por la atención prestada. Excelente día para todos.

Comment: Te ayudaría ver el contenido de `$data`. Si lo puedes cargar a la pregunta nos dará una mejor vista del panorama.

Comment: Esta es la respuesta que me arroja, gracias por la ayuda array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["idcam"]=> string(2) "54" ["datos"]=> array(3) { [0]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["nombre"]=> string(7) "nombre1" ["direccion"]=> string(4) "dir1" } [1]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "2" ["nombre"]=> string(7) "nombre2" ["direccion"]=> string(4) "dir2" } } } }

Answer (score 0):

Necesitamos saber, que información tiene el `$data`.

Puedes ejecutar un `var_dump($data)`, después de la línea donde declaras el ( `$data = json_decode($json,true);  /* ahora en $data tenemos el objeto que nos enviaron x json, */`);

También recordarte, que se debería ajustar ese código de nuevo, ya que cuando os toque actualizar el PHP del servidor, hay métodos que os van a dejar de funcionar, como `mysql_real_escape_string` ([mysql_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)), que dejo de funcionar en php 7 y posteriores.

Aquí dejo el soporte de las versiones de PHP ([Soporte Versiones PHP](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php))

Comment: Esto no es precisamente una respuesta. Podrías haberle hecho la solicitud por medio de un comentario.

Comment: Esta es la respuesta que me arroja, gracias por la ayuda array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["idcam"]=> string(2) "54" ["datos"]=> array(3) { [0]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["nombre"]=> string(7) "nombre1" ["direccion"]=> string(4) "dir1" } [1]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "2" ["nombre"]=> string(7) "nombre2" ["direccion"]=> string(4) "dir2" } } } }